# System environment variables not appearing in sudo

Tags: debian, sudo, environment-variables

I have the following line my /etc/environment file:

```
BROKER_URL=tcp://xxx.30.8.163:61616
```

I run this and get:

```
$ set|grep BROKER_URL
BROKER_URL=tcp://xxx.30.8.163:61616
```

Then, I run:

```
$ sudo bash
# set|grep BROKER_URL
#
```

This is supposed to be a system wide environment variable. Why doesn't it show up in my sudo shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/etc/environment` is a file [used by PAM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123571/how-to-add-new-elements-to-path-for-daemons-or-other-best-practices/123575#123575), meaning it is processed by a log in, which `sudo bash` does not do, and (from `man sudoers`):

> **Command environment**
>
> Since environment variables can influence program behavior, sudoers provides a means to restrict which
>        variables from the user's environment are inherited by the command to be run.  There are two distinct
>        ways sudoers can deal with environment variables.
>
> By default, the env_reset option is enabled.  This causes commands to be executed with a new, minimal
>        environment.  On AIX (and **Linux systems *without* PAM**), the environment is initialized with the contents
>        of the /etc/environment file.

Note that most GNU/linux systems do use PAM. You could try to get around this by using `sudo -i`, to use a login shell. However, this likely will still not work as "login shell" refers to how bash invokes itself, which does not include sourcing `/etc/environment`, and you are not actually logging in via PAM.

Your best bet is probably to [configure sudo](https://superuser.com/a/232258/257378) to do what you want.