# sudo causes envsubst to print empty output

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

I have a script that exports some variables and in some places uses `sudo`.

This is a simple example:

```
export Name=John
sudo envsubst < SourceFile > TargetFile
```

And if the `SourceFile` has a `$Name` variable in it, then it would be printed as empty.

If I remove `sudo` then it works.

Does `export` work universally for all users? How can I export a variable for the entire machine?

Comment: It's unclear what the question is. Is it why the `sudo` command does not work (see [System environment variables not appearing in sudo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125229) or [similar questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudo+environment-variables)), or is it about setting an environment variable for all users?  Also note that `export` creates an environment variable that will be visible by the current shell and any child processes, unless they explicitly delete the variable (like `sudo` does).  There is no way to "export to the whole machine".

Answer (score 10):

By default, `sudo` clears its environment except for a few variables that it passes along sanitised (and a few that it explicitly sets to sane values) as a security measure.

If allowed by the sudo configuration, you may be able to use the `-E`/`--preserve-env` variable to work around that.

In any case, environment variables, like command arguments, is something that is passed from command to command upon execution, it's not something that lives in some ethereal space accessed by every process (for that, there's the file system), so *export*ing *a variable for the entire machine* doesn't make sense.

Also, the `envsubst` command doesn't need any special privilege so it doesn't make sense to run  it as `root`. If you're doing that in an attempt  to open the source file or create the target file as `root`, that's misguided because in:

> ```
> sudo envsubst < SourceFile > TargetFile
> ```

The redirections are done by the shell invoking `sudo` so as the original user.

It's a command that opens those files that you'd need to run as `root`:

```
sudo cat SourceFile | envsubst | sudo sh -c 'exec cat > TargetFile'
```

Here using `cat` to open (and read and pass along) the SourceFile, and `sh` to open the TargetFile (and `cat` writing the data there).

If on a GNU system, you could also do:

```
sudo dd bs=64k status=none if=SourceFile |
  envsubst |
  sudo dd bs=64k status=none of=TargetFile
```

See [Does Unix have a command to read from stdin and write to a file (like tee without sending output to stdout)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/712933) for details and other approaches.